# How to change the app startup screen, in Android, when NavigationStyle is Slide

Tags: android, smart-device, genexus

I have two questions for a Slide App StartUp, when executed in Android.

1 - Is there any way of changing the menu icon color?

2 - I am using a SplashScreen but, in Android, after the SplashScreen, a blank panel is presented to the user. Is there any way of filling this panel with an image? (Note: in iOS this startup panel is filled with the splashscreen image).

[image: Visual description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1_ Yes, this icon is copy of the system icon and change with the **"Android Base Style"**. If you use **"Dark"** it will use one icon and if you use **"Light"** it will use other.

Also you can use a custom one if you override the file:

gx_drawer_icon_dark.png

in all the drawables folders:

Android\FlexibleClient\res\drawable-hdpi

Android\FlexibleClient\res\drawable-xhdpi

etc.

2_ You should use the **Slide.Start** event here.:

http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?Slide.Start+Event,

and call an intro SDPanel

Comment: Thank you very much!
1 - Perfect solution!
2 - This solution does exactly what I want, for Android. Is there any way of conditioning the call only for the Android platform?

Comment: I was already using the slide.start for my authentication procedure. I can't do the call because of an issue for iOS reported here (http://www2.gxtechnical.com/portal/hgxpp001.aspx?15,4,61,O,E,0,,36141). The workaround proposed stops working when I add the call. So, the solution for question #2 works great for Android, but will make the iOS version to stop working...

Comment: It would be great if I could do something like this: If Platform = 'Android' SDWelcome.call ;)

Comment: You can use ClientInformation: 
http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?ClientInformation+API,
 if ClientInformation.OSName = "Android"